# ¿Cómo repetir un análisis Kruskal-Wallis on un bucle 'for' y obtener una solución única para cada variable analizada?

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

soy bastante nuevo en la programación y en R, así que ando muy perdido con este problema:

Necesito hacer un análisis de Kruskal-Wallis para un número elevado de variables numéricas respecto de diferentes variables categóricas y obtener un valor de significación para cada una de las variables numéricas.
Mis datos son más o menos así:

```
Sample,Nunatak,Slope,Altitude,Depth,Fluoride,Acetate,Formiate,Chloride,Nitrate  (...)
    m4,1,1,1,1,0.044,0.884,0.522,0.198,0.021
    m6,1,1,1,2,0.059,0.852,0.733,0.664,0.038
    m7,1,1,1,3,0.082,0.339,1.496,0.592,0.034
    m8,1,1,2,1,0.112,0.812,2.709,0.357,0.014
    m10,1,1,2,2,0.088,0.768,2.535,0.379,0
    m11,1,1,3,1,0.101,0.336,4.504,0.229,0
    m13,1,1,3,2,0.092,0.681,1.862,0.671,0.018
    m14,1,2,2,1,0.12,1.055,3.018,0.771,0
    m16,1,2,2,2,0.102,1.019,1.679,1.435,0
    m17,1,2,2,3,0.26,0.631,0.505,0.574,0.008'
    (...)
```

Siendo `Nunatak`, `Slope`, `Altitude` y `Depth` las variables categóricas y el resto (`Fluoride`...) las numéricas.

Para no tener que repetir:

```
kruskal.test("Factor a analizar 1"~"Variable de categorización 1",  data=env_fact)
```

Tantas veces como variables tengo, un compañero me ha ayudado a crear un bucle 'for' como el que sigue:

```
my.variables <- colnames(env_fact)
for(i in 1:length(my.variables)) {
    if(my.variables[i] == 'Categorical_var') {
        next
    } else {
        kruskal.test(env_fact[,i], env_fact$Categorical_var)
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, no conseguimos escribir un código que nos permita sacar los valores del test para cada una de las variables numéricas (my.variables) que analizamos, sino que solo hemos conseguido sacar un valor de significación para el análisis como si se realizara con todas las variables numéricas a la vez.

¿Alguna idea de cómo modificar el pequeño código para poder tener en pantalla o en un output los valores del Kruskal-Wallis test para cada una de las variables numéricas que necesito analizar?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, para hacer reproducible mi respuesta, cargamos los datos que pusiste de ejemplo en un `data.frame`:

```
env_fact <- read.table(text="Sample,Nunatak,Slope,Altitude,Depth,Fluoride,Acetate,Formiate,Chloride,Nitrate
m4,1,1,1,1,0.044,0.884,0.522,0.198,0.021
m6,1,1,1,2,0.059,0.852,0.733,0.664,0.038
m7,1,1,1,3,0.082,0.339,1.496,0.592,0.034
m8,1,1,2,1,0.112,0.812,2.709,0.357,0.014
m10,1,1,2,2,0.088,0.768,2.535,0.379,0
m11,1,1,3,1,0.101,0.336,4.504,0.229,0
m13,1,1,3,2,0.092,0.681,1.862,0.671,0.018
m14,1,2,2,1,0.12,1.055,3.018,0.771,0
m16,1,2,2,2,0.102,1.019,1.679,1.435,0
m17,1,2,2,3,0.26,0.631,0.505,0.574,0.008", sep=',', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Bien, por lo que muestras, estás queriendo aplicar el test de Kruskal-Wallis mediante el uso de una formula, individualmente sería algo como esto:

```
kruskal.test(Nunatak ~ Fluoride,  data=env_fact)
```

En este ejemplo `Nunatak ~ Fluoride` es la formula, y para poder hacer todos los tests, que entiendo, son entre cada variable categórica y cada variable numérica, deberíamos poder definir dinámicamente esta formula. Para definir una formula, por ejemplo desde una cadena, tenemos `as.formula()` que eventualmente nos permite hacer algo así: `as.formula("Nunatak ~ Fluoride")`, nota que lo que estamos pasando es una cadena.

Dicho esto, definimos en primer lugar los dos grupos de variables:

```
categorical_vars <- c('Nunatak','Slope','Altitude','Depth')
numerical_vars <- c('Fluoride','Acetate','Formiate','Chloride','Nitrate')
```

Lo siguiente, es hacer un ciclo por cada `categorical_vars` y en cada iteración, otro ciclo por cada `numerical_vars`, adicionalmente, será conveniente guardar la salida de cada test, en una lista, para poder acceder luego a los resultados de los mismos:

```
kret = list()
i <- 1
for (c in categorical_vars) {
    for (n in numerical_vars) {
        f <- as.formula(paste(c, '~', n))
        kret[[deparse(f)]] <- kruskal.test(f,  data=env_fact)
        i <- i + 1
    }
}
```

Lo que logras con esto es: (a) correr el test entre cada variable categórica y cada numérica (b) finalizar con una lista `kret` dónde estarán los resultados de cada uno de los tests. Para acceder luego a la lista y los resultados, puedes hacerlo por índice:

```
kret[7]

$`Slope ~ Acetate`

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Slope by Acetate
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 9, df = 9, p-value = 0.4373
```

O como hemos nombrado cada elemento con la formula, podríamos acceder directamente por estas:

```
kret['Slope ~ Nitrate']

$`Slope ~ Nitrate`

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Slope by Nitrate
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 4.7143, df = 6, p-value = 0.5809
```

Comment: Guau, increíble.  Voy ahora mismo a ponerlo en práctica. Mil gracias por la ayuda. Está claro que, aunque tenía más o menos claro lo que había que hacer, no tenía ni idea de como hacerlo.